# how to renable the close [x} button of excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that disable the close [x] function of excel. after completed enter ID, I need to enable again the button.

I have this part that disable the [x],

```
Public FlagToClose As Boolean
Sub Enter_1()
    FlagToClose = False

    'code
    '.....................

    FlagToClose = True
End Sub
```

for the `workbook` module I have this,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    FlagToClose = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not FlagToClose Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

then how to enable again the close[x] function?

Comment: Your code looks good as is. You turn your flag to `false` so the workbook can't close (because of your `Workbook_BeforeClose` subroutine, then you toggle flagToClose back on. Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

To re-enable closing, run this short macro before closing:

```
Sub ev_off()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub
```

Comment: The sub ev_off() works. So before I run the code, I would like to create another sub so that the user can key in the same value match in the sub_Enter1() to enable closing. How to link the value in between the two sub?

Comment: @JiaWeiLee  I do not understand.

Comment: Initially the user will click macro 1 that have the input box 1 for the user to enter numeric value to disable the close[x] function. After do all the necessary, the user will click the macro 2 to enter the same numeric value in the input box 2. If there is mismatch between the value input in input box 1 and input box 2 then the [x] function still remain disable. How to link the value of the input box 1 (in sub 1) to value of input box 2 ( in sub 2)